# MAMP not restoring my databases

Tags: database, macos, crash, mamp

I connected to MAMP (on Mac) a few days ago to work on an old Opencart website. On the Admin page of that site, the admin password didn't work (it was supposed to be root for the user and root for the password). Stupidly I tried to change it through MAMP and it created a big mess. I couldn't login after that so even more stupidly, I deleted MAMP (I know...) and reinstalled it.
So now MAMP works properly, and I can login. But my databases are gone (including that Opencart website). I pointed the Document Root to the correct folder, and even tried to create a new database with the name of the old one, but I can't access to them through localhost:8888/websitename.
So I wonder if I lost my website for ever, or if there is a solution...?
Thanks for your help!
Cheers
edit: I didn't delete the folders with all the website databases, there are still in my Localhost folder.

Comment: if you deleted mamp, the database is most likely to vanish. happens in xampp all the time .

Comment: Nothing positive anyone?

Comment: I think that basically I need to export my old database to import it to the new install of MAMP, but I have no idea on how to export it from the folder...

Comment: MAMP is a package which comes with FTD, MySQL and Apache Web Server. When you uninstall it, everything above gets uninstalled. MySQL too. Last try can be checking your MySQL directory for .db extension files. If not found, MySQL got deleted with all the user files !

Comment: Thanks Saru95! Do you think I could at least put that website online? Sorry if it sounds dumb...

Comment: If it is deleted, you'll have to code again and then you can put it online !